# Como formatar mensagem JSON para ler facilmente

Tags: json, console, formatação

Preciso fazer DEBUG de mensagem JSON. Gostaria de um ter disponível um mecanismo de formatação parecido com aquele que tem no Eclipse para formatação de código Java e JavaScript, porém via console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem vários formatadores para mensagem JSON mas o que mais gosto é `JSBeautifier`. Você pode usá-lo simplesmente copiando o seu código para o Clipboard e abrir o site [JSBeautifier.ORG](http://jsbeautifier.org) e em seguida colando o conteudo no campo indicado. Tecle `Ctrl+Enter` para executar a formatação.

O `JSBeautifier`  também suporta o uso via console vi `NODE JS` ou instalando a versão `Python`.

Veja os detalhes em http://jsbeautifier.org.

Comment: Tem também o http://jsonlint.com/, que valida e formata o JSON.

Answer (score 1):

A ferramenta [`underscore-cli`](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli) deve servir muito bem para esse propósito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode estar usando do seguinte modo:

```
cat data.json | underscore print --color
```